# How to get div elements between a range of numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I want to get elements between a range of numbers, let's say between 10 and 15 from these:

```html
<div class="1">....</div>
<div class="2">....</div>
<div class="3">....</div>
...
...
...
<div class="20">....</div>
```

#### Desired Output:

```html
<div class="10">....</div>
<div class="11">....</div>
<div class="12">....</div>
<div class="13">....</div>
<div class="14">....</div>
<div class="15">....</div>
```

Comment: Are these divs in a common conatiner?

Answer (score 3):

While the JS solution is probably better, mainly because it's more flexible, I want to mention the CSS solution, even though it has more limitations.

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-block;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}
div div {
  width: 50px;
}
div:nth-child(n+10):nth-child(-n+15) { /* From the 10th child up to the 15th child */
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div>01</div>
<div>02</div>
<div>03</div>
<div>04</div>
<div>05</div>
<div>06</div>
<div>07</div>
<div>08</div>
<div>09</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20</div>
</div>
```

By combining two `nth-child` selectors you can specify a range of elements.
You can use this selector in JS as well

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(n+10):nth-child(-n+15)');
```

The downside is that it will work well only if all the elements are siblings and the only children of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

The following example only works with this specific case where the classes are numbered. This is not a common scenario. Most would use unique IDs and then common Classes for grouping.

```js
$(function() {
  function selectBetween(start, finish) {
    var selects = [];
    for (start; start <= finish; start++) {
      selects.push("." + start);
    }
    return $(selects.join(", "));
  }

  var myDivs = selectBetween(10, 15);
  console.log(myDivs.length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">....</div>
<div class="2">....</div>
<div class="3">....</div>
<div class="4">....</div>
<div class="5">....</div>
<div class="6">....</div>
<div class="7">....</div>
<div class="8">....</div>
<div class="9">....</div>
<div class="10">....</div>
<div class="11">....</div>
<div class="12">....</div>
<div class="13">....</div>
<div class="14">....</div>
<div class="15">....</div>
<div class="16">....</div>
<div class="17">....</div>
<div class="18">....</div>
<div class="19">....</div>
<div class="20">....</div>
```

Console will show `6`.

Comment: Op wants 10-15 aka * elements returned :)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen and that's exactly what is returned. better than using `[class*='1']`

Comment: if you remove `.length` from your code, it return 10-14 not 10-15 as desired result.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen good call, I adjusted the logic to `<=` to get all of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `slice` will be sufficient.

`[...document.getElementsByTagName("div")].slice(10,5)`

Comment: `.slice(10,5)` returns an empty array

Comment: Highly inefficient and incorrect as you'll end up getting all the `div` present in the DOM.

Comment: of course the selector should be replace with the real selector(based on container, class, attr etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')]
  .filter((e) => Number(e.classList.value) >= 10)
  .filter((e) => Number(e.classList.value) <= 15)
  .map((e) => console.log(e.outerHTML))

 // <div class="10">....</div>
 // <div class="11">....</div>
 // <div class="12">....</div>
 // <div class="13">....</div>
 // <div class="14">....</div>
 // <div class="15">....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map over an array of length of a number of elements required and use `getElementsByClassName` method to get the required elements between the range.

```js
const getElements = (min, max) => {
  // construct an array of length of number of elements b/w min & max
  // and then map the required elements with the className selector
  return [...new Array((max - min) + 1)]
    .map((_, index) => document.getElementsByClassName(index + min));
}

console.log(getElements(10, 15));
```

```html
<div class="0">0</div>
<div class="1">1</div>
<div class="2">2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>
<div class="4">4</div>
<div class="5">5</div>
<div class="6">6</div>
<div class="7">7</div>
<div class="8">8</div>
<div class="9">9</div>
<div class="10">10</div>
<div class="11">11</div>
<div class="12">12</div>
<div class="13">13</div>
<div class="14">14</div>
<div class="15">15</div>
<div class="16">16</div>
<div class="17">17</div>
<div class="18">18</div>
<div class="19">19</div>
<div class="20">20</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get required output, first I would fetch all divs on the page,
convert resulting nodelist into arrays so that I can apply arrays' filter
method and then I would populate another div with outer HTML of the filtered
arrays.

Here, I have created an arrow function which does filtering using parameters
to make filter reusable.  The code reads as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Get Div Elements from n number to n number</title>
    <script>

        window.onload = ()=>{

            // get all divs on this page
            let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div')

            // arrow function to get required divs where
            // start is int, stop is int and divs is nodelist
            const getDivsBetween = (start, stop, divs)=>{
                // convert nodelist to JavaScript array
                let theDivs = Array.from(divs)

                // filter the array 
                let retVal = theDivs.filter((element)=>{
                    // convert className to integer for checking
                    // whether className is between the values
                    let className = parseInt(element.className)

                    // return selected element
                    if (className >= start && className <=stop) return element 
                })

                return retVal // return array containing filtered elements
            }
            
            // get required divs
            let outPutDivs = getDivsBetween(10, 15, allDivs)

            // get div where output will go 
            let theOutputDiv = document.getElementById('output')

            // populate output div with filtered divs outer html
            // to get required output
            outPutDivs.map((element)=>{
                let thisDiv = document.createElement('div')
                thisDiv.append(element.outerHTML)
                theOutputDiv.append(thisDiv)
            })

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div>Here are original divs</div>
    <div id="originals">
        <div class="1">....</div>
        <div class="2">....</div>
        <div class="3">....</div>
        <div class="4">....</div>
        <div class="5">....</div>
        <div class="6">....</div>
        <div class="7">....</div>
        <div class="8">....</div>
        <div class="9">....</div>
        <div class="10">....</div>
        <div class="11">....</div>
        <div class="12">....</div>
        <div class="13">....</div>
        <div class="14">....</div>
        <div class="15">....</div>
        <div class="16">....</div>
        <div class="17">....</div>
        <div class="18">....</div>
        <div class="19">....</div>
        <div class="20">....</div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div>Here is required output</div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    

</body>
</html>
```